# Inserir registro em uma tabela e usar ID recém gerado para inserir registro em tabela relacionada

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Tenho um `insert` em que eu salvo um registro, e preciso utilizar o resultado do valor salvo em outro `insert`.

```
Empresa emp = new Empresa();
emp.setId(1);
emp.setNome("Nome da empresa");

repository1.saveAndFlush(emp);

RelacaoEmp relEmp = new RelacaoEmp();
relEmp.setId(100);
relEmp.setIdEmp(1); //O mesmo Id Cadastrado na empresa
relEmp.setTpEmp(10);

repository2.save(relEmp);
```

Quando efetivo essa operação ele fala que a empresa 1 não existe.

Existe alguma forma para eu efetivar o registro do `repository1` antes de executar o `repository2` para não dar este problema?

Comment: isso está dentro de uma transaction?

Comment: Veja se isso ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45491551/8133067

Answer (score 0):

```
Empresa emp = new Empresa();
Empresa empSalva = new Empresa();

emp.setId(1);
emp.setNome("Nome da empresa");

empSalva = repository1.saveAndFlush(emp);

RelacaoEmp relEmp = new RelacaoEmp();
relEmp.setId(100);
relEmp.setIdEmp(empSalva.getId()); //O mesmo Id Cadastrado na empresa
relEmp.setTpEmp(10);

repository2.save(relEmp);
```

Comment: Já resolveu o problema? Isso é a solucao?